# How to vectorize passing a function to two numpy arrays: 3D and 2D?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I have two multidimensional `numpy` arrays: `x` is 3D and `y` is 2D.

If I have a function `foo(a, b)`, which takes as inputs two 2D arrays, how can I pass to `foo` my multidimensional arrays and iterate over `x`'s 3rd dimension in a vectorized way in order to get a list of `foo`'s results?

I have been trying to do this with `np.vectorize`, but it iterates through the rows of the arrays and yields an error, so I am stuck.

Comment: Even if it worked `np.vectorize` doesn't offer any speed improvement.  If you can't rewrite `foo`, it's hard to beat the iteration: `foo(a[:,:,i], b]`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the function's signature using the `signature` keyword. This will, however, try to use the last dimensions of each input, so you'd have to manually transpose. Example

```
F = np.vectorize(np.matmul, signature='(m,n),(n,l)->(m,l)', otypes=(float,))
A = np.arange(12).reshape(2, 2, 3)
B = np.diag((1.5, 2.5))
# F(A.transpose(2,0,1), B)
# array([[[ 0. ,  7.5],
#         [ 9. , 22.5]],
# 
#        [[ 1.5, 10. ],
#         [10.5, 25. ]],
#
#        [[ 3. , 12.5],
#         [12. , 27.5]]])
```

As pointed out by @hpaulj in the comments `vectorize` is a convenience function, not a performance enhancer.